# GAE datastore, GetMulti() with Projection?

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

My application puts together a grouping of many different Kinds of data for a report to the user, this report takes a while to compile and it is useful for the user to see this snapshot at a later date, so I save a copy of the data compiled into a separate Kind in the datastore.  Then, possibly months later, the user pull up the copy that I saved, but I want to query the datastore for just one specific status field on each entity that may have changed since they originally ran the report, to see if that entity has changed since they first viewed the report.

So, I have all of the keys I need, I could do a datastore.GetMulti().  But there could be thousands of entities, and each one has many fields, so I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of querying the datastore to get just this one field, instead of the entire set of data.  Something like a combination of a projection query and a GetMulti(), but I can't find anything like that in the docs, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection queries don't have to be only on a single entity. You can do exactly this with a projection query. In your case, something like this:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("EntityKindYouDefinedName").Project("status_property")
```

[See the doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/projectionqueries) for more information on how to process the results of this projection query.